# Can't grab a DOM node using parentNode in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

i am working on an adapted version of [Adam Maschek's excellent image map tool](http://code.google.com/p/imgmap/). The new functionality i have added are left/top/width/height input boxes so that you can have pixel control over the hotspot position/size. I have got it working fine in FF and Chrome but the issue i am having is in IE 7/8 where it just will not retrieve the value of the input box on change.

Here is the function where the issue is occuring:

```
function gui_dimension_change(e) {

function changeAreaPos(areaNum, inputVal, cssAttrib, coordPos) {
var coordsBox = document.getElementsByClassName('img_coords')[areaNum],
    newCoordsVal = coordsBox.value.split(","),
    newWidth = "",
    newHeight = "",
    imCode = imcodeContainer.value,
    pattern = imCode.match(/\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+/g);

    myimgmap.areas[areaNum].style[cssAttrib] = inputVal;

    if (cssAttrib === "left" || cssAttrib === "top") {
        myimgmap.areas[areaNum].label.style[cssAttrib] = inputVal;
        newCoordsVal[coordPos] = inputVal;
    } else if (cssAttrib === "width") {
        myimgmap.areas[areaNum].width = inputVal;
        newWidth = parseInt(newCoordsVal[0]) + parseInt(inputVal);
        newCoordsVal[coordPos] = newWidth;
    } else if (cssAttrib === "height") {
        myimgmap.areas[areaNum].height = inputVal;
        newHeight = parseInt(newCoordsVal[1]) + parseInt(inputVal);
        newCoordsVal[coordPos] = newHeight;
    }

    newCoordsVal = newCoordsVal.join(",");
    myimgmap.areas[areaNum].lastInput = newCoordsVal;
    coordsBox.value = newCoordsVal;

    imCode = imCode.replace(pattern[areaNum], newCoordsVal);
    imcodeContainer.value = imCode;

};

    // alert(this);
    // alert(this.parentNode);
    // alert(this.parentNode.id);

var inputParent = this.parentNode,
    inputVal = this.value,
    whichBox = this.name,
    areaNum = inputParent.id.replace("img_area_", ""),
    imcodeContainer = document.getElementById('html_container');

switch(whichBox)
{
    case "img_left":
        changeAreaPos(areaNum, inputVal, "left", 0);
    break;
    case "img_top":
        changeAreaPos(areaNum, inputVal, "top", 1);
    break;
    case "img_width":
        changeAreaPos(areaNum, inputVal, "width", 2);
    break;
    case "img_height":
        changeAreaPos(areaNum, inputVal, "height", 3);
    break;
}

}
```

The function is called like so:

```
myimgmap.addEvent(props[id].getElementsByTagName('input')[5], 'change', gui_dimension_change);
myimgmap.addEvent(props[id].getElementsByTagName('input')[6], 'change', gui_dimension_change);
myimgmap.addEvent(props[id].getElementsByTagName('input')[7], 'change', gui_dimension_change);
myimgmap.addEvent(props[id].getElementsByTagName('input')[8], 'change', gui_dimension_change);
```

So on the change event i can't set inputParent with this.parentNode, and can't grab the value of the input box with this.value either. Works in FF/Chrome but not IE 7/8, any ideas why IE has a problem with parentNode and getting the value?

Comment: Can you please post a more specific portion of the code? One that produces the bug you're describing. Trust me, very few people will actually copy and add the referenced files and then test it let alone reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i figured out the solution in case anyone cares. It was all because IE handles event targets differently to other browsers, so i did the following:

```
var obj = (myimgmap.isMSIE) ? window.event.srcElement : e.currentTarget;
```

and used obj instead of this.

Stupid IE!!!